# remove onClick attribute in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

a checkbox on my page has the onclick event to enable a button when it is checked, and disable it when it is not checked. sometimes I need the button to be disabled completely, but I don't want it to be invisible.

the checkbox looks like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb_start" runat="server" onClick="cb_start_click()"/>
<script>
    var cb = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cb_start");
    var btn = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_start");
    function cb_start_click(){
        btn.disabled = !cb.checked;
    }
</script>
```

In the code behind I tried this, but it did not work:

```
cb_start.Attributes.Remove("onClick");
if (somecase) cb_start.Attributes.Add("onClick", "cb_start_click()");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove the listener. You can place your `if (somecase)` in `cb_start_click()` callback function to avoid the button from getting enabled.

Comment: I don't think I'm able to get the necessairy information inside JS, since it comes from an sql database. I created a workaround by making the button invisible and making another button, in the same place with the same appearance visible, but it is statically disabled. Not a very good solution, but it does its job.

Comment: What if the function is javascript-only?

Answer (score -1):

If you want remove the event, just type in cs file:

```
rodape.Attributes.Remove("onclick");
```

Example on page...

Before remove event (using developer tools):
[image]

After remove event (using developer tools):
[image]